# What is the connection between Skyline (2010) and Beyond Skyline (2017)?

Tags: continuity, skyline, beyond-skyline

I watched the 2017 movie [Beyond Skyline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Skyline) and it did not feel like a second part of a movie. Then on Wikipedia I read this line:

> Beyond Skyline is a 2017 American science fiction action thriller film directed by Liam O'Donnell and stars Frank Grillo, Bojana Novakovic, Iko Uwais, Callan Mulvey, Yayan Ruhian, Betty Gabriel and Antonio Fargas. **It is a direct sequel to the 2010 film [Skyline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyline_(2010_film))**.

So if [Beyond Skyline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Skyline) is a sequel to [Skyline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyline_(2010_film)), why did the movie not mention anything from the previous one?

How are the movies really connected?

Comment: Based on the wikipedia article itself, "At the same time where the first film left off"... So the sequel occurs for another group in another part of the world or place I guess and thus both are not intertwined... But of course, I have not watched the film...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How the movies are really connected?

*Beyond Skyline* is direct sequel to *Skyline* and takes place just after the events of first film. Jarrod's transformation happened in *Skyline* and Elaine and Jarrod were the main leads from the first film.

> Why the movie did not mention anything from the previous one?

That's quite normal to not talk about a first film in a sequel. Most sequels continue the story from where the first one left  offand don't show a recap from the first film. But *Beyond Skyline* did address the first film when Elaine gives Mark updates about what happened in the first film and how Jarrod's transformation happened.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, even though it says it’s a direct sequel, and it is...the two movies overlap quite a bit during the first 45 minutes or more of the film. They are shown from two different perspectives. Skyline was mostly filmed from outside the city in that fancy high rise just off the coast. Beyond Skyline was filmed mostly from the inner city...until everyone was taken.

A few key notifiers...the bomber drone that blew up the alien main ship. The alien ship then started to rebuild itself.

And then of course, they finally show Jerrod helping Mark find his son...Mark finds pregnant Elaine...from that point on is new/different.